# How to create a google cloud platform connection on airflow command line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have been trying to create a google cloud platform connection on Airflow command line using

```
gcloud connections -a --conn_id google_cloud_my_conn --conn_type  google_cloud_platform --conn_extra "{extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path=credential.json}"
```

So, when I ran the command it create a connection, however it doesn't add correctly extra parameters to the connection.

I'm using airflow v1.10.2 running on Ubuntu 18.04, I have created other connection like cloud sql connection and it works fine but it doesn't work with google cloud platform.

When run the command it shows the following details on the web interface
https://i.postimg.cc/PJ5RKGS5/result.png
however I expected something like this 
https://i.postimg.cc/ry7HxHSM/expected.png

Answer (score 1):

There is other post with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50040717/add-gcp-credentials-to-airflow-via-command-line).

I add more parameters to the connections

```
airflow connections -a \
  --conn_id=my_conn_gcp \
  --conn_type=google_cloud_platform \
  --conn_extra='{ "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_path":" '`
        `'my_credetnial.json", '`
    `'"extra__google_cloud_platform__project": '`
        `'"project_name", '`
    `'"extra__google_cloud_platform__scope":  '`
        `'"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, '`
        `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only, '`
        `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control, '`
        `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, '`
        `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write"}'
```